# .net maui animation problems on android 13

Tags: .net

Why does it not work on Android 13 when adding animation in the .net maui project?

When lowering the target version on which it runs ( in my case  Android 9), the project crashes until I return it to android 13. thank you in advance

Comment: Could you add more details about the issue? Currently it's unclear what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: all animation methods change properties immediately without taking into account the specified time. although on android 9 and windows, all methods work correctly.

Comment: found a temporary solution to the problem-you must disable the power saving mode (((()